# SQL Sorting in 'Union All' Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 4 select table with `Union All` as connect0r to these tables.

```
Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[]
where []

Union All

Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[]
where []

Union All

Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[]
where []

Union All

Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[]
where []
```

I already tried to make `order by [a] asc` in last line or in each `select` line, but it's still didn't works and became errors.

Comment: Can you show us complete sql? Symbols `[]` and `[a]` doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: [a] is a table name? You shouldnt be trying to order by a table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first `select` you must have column with alias `A`

```
Select col1 as a [...] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[] where []    
Union All   
Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[] where []    
Union All    
Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[] where []    
Union All    
Select [] from [a] inner join [b] on a.[] = b.[] where []
order by a
```

Comment: the condition in each "where" is different.
so, if i do like @parado write, it's only the last "select" that ordered well.

Comment: @anakpanti You ordering by column not condition

Comment: @anakpanti - you only apply one `ORDER BY` for a `UNION [ALL]` query - and it applies to the *entire* result set, not just the "last select"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put your ORDER BY clause at the end of the statement, referencing to first select column names/aliases.

Eg.

```
SELECT a,b customName
FROM T1 
WHERE a = 'yourFilter'
UNION ALL
SELECT foo1,foo2 
FROM T2 
WHERE foo2 IN ('otherFilter','otherFilter2')
ORDER BY customName DESC, a
```